# Magento 1.9 onepage checkout stuck on billing information for downloadable/virtual products

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, onepage-checkout, downloadable, virtual-products

I have Magento CE 1.9.2.2, and when I try to check out with ONLY downloadable and/or virtual products, my onepage checkout won't move past the **billing information** step. Clicking the continue button causes the text **loading next step** to appear for a moment, then the button comes back and no progress has been made.

In the google chrome console, a javascript error appears:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property `getElementsByTagName` of null

and every time I click "continue", i get this in the console:
XHR finished loading: POST `my-magento-site.org/checkout/process/verifyBilling/`.

I get that second message in the console over and over when I click **continue** and the first message once when the page loads. The javascript error is coming from here, in `my-magento-site.org/checkout/onepage/(index)`:

```
document.getElementById("shipping-buttons-container").getElementsByTagName("button")[0].onclick = qas_first_pass_shipping;
```

Though i don't know where this code is located in my site's source.

I have tried numerous solutions to similar questions I have found on this site (and others) but none have worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is it working for other product?

Comment: yes it works fine for any products besides downloadable or virtual products. It also works fine if the cart contains (in addition to downloadable/virtual products) physical, shipped products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using this module?

**Experian QAS Email Verification** - 
http://shop.perficient.com/email-verification

If so, I believe that the issue lies in the code that it executes within checkout.

Remove/disable this module and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: this worked! thanks so much. Though it's nice to have email/address validation, it's better to have my checkout working. :)

Comment: No problem.  The issue can likely be fixed.  If you purchased the module recently, I would try reaching out to them for a fix!